# How can I override the client credentials' default Base64 encoding in OAuth authorization API call?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have established an OAuth Server. Currently when I make a call to the authorization endpoint (/oauth/authorize), I need to pass the client_id and client_secret (client_id:client_secret) in request header in Base64 encoded form. How can I override the encoding method?

I am using Spring Security framework.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird. What you have to present when you make an API call is not a pair of client ID and client secret but an **access token**.

Passing client credentials to an [authorization endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1) and a [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) is described in "[2.3. Client Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3)" in **[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)**. However, it is different from **[RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)** (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage), which defines three ways to pass an access token to APIs.

---

**Additional answer for the modified question**

(1) **[Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2)** and (2) embedding client credentials in the request-body are standard ways defined in RFC 6749, [2.3.1. Client Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1).

Authorization server implementations may support other HTTP authentication schemes. The following is the paragraph written in RFC 6748, [2.3.2. Other Authentication Methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.2):

> **The authorization server MAY support any suitable HTTP authentication scheme** matching its security requirements.  When using other authentication methods, the authorization server MUST define a mapping between the client identifier (registration record) and authentication scheme.

If Spring Security framework does not support other ways than Basic Authentication, you have to encode your client credentials in Base64, which is again the standard way defined in RFC 6749.

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie to OAuth. I have edited the question appropriately.